# Can you use output from function as @Bindable when input is @Bindable

Tags: swift, data-binding

I have some @Bindable variables in a view, and I want to use them as input to a function. I then want to use the output as a bindable input in another view. I want to ensure that when one of the inputs change, the view in which I'm using the output, updates. I was hoping something like this would work, but it doesn't

```
struct GraphView: View {
    @Binding var list: [SomeClass]
    @Binding var options: OptionClass

    var body: some View {
        PlotView(refinedData: $(SomeService.dataRefiner(list: $list, options: $options)
        }

    }
}
```

Can it be make to work, or should I structure my code in a different way?

Answer (score 1):

A `Binding` is basically something with get and set, so you can write your own custom binding.

For example:

```swift
var refinedData: Binding<MyData>(
    get: {
        SomeService.dataRefiner(list: list, options: options)
    },
    set: {
        // your code here
    }

var body: some View {
    PlotView(refinedData: refinedData)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the direction of custom bindings. I had to put the defintion of refinedData inside the view, because list and options were not available at initialisation. I didn't need the setter, but was not allowed to keep it empty, so I put _ = $0. MyData is the type returned by SomeService.dataRefiner.